# How to get the download progress in bytes using Alamofire 4?

Tags: ios, swift, networking, download, alamofire

I'm currently working on an iOS project which requires me to download 10 different files at once. I know the file size and the size of all the files combined but I'm struggling to find a way to calculate the progress across all download tasks.

```
progress.totalUnitCount = object.size // The size of all the files combined
    for file in files {
        let destination: DownloadRequest.DownloadFileDestination = { _, _ in
            let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.applicationSupportDirectory,
                                                           FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true)
            let documentDirectoryPath: String = path[0]
            let destinationURLForFile = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentDirectoryPath)
            return (destinationURLForFile, [.removePreviousFile, .createIntermediateDirectories])
        }

        Alamofire.download(file.urlOnServer, to: destination)
            .downloadProgress(queue: .main, closure: { progress in

            })
            .response { response in
                if let error = response.error {
                    print(error)
                }
        }
    }
```

Most of this code is just for context.

I discovered, that up to Alamofire 3 there was this call:

```
 .progress { bytesRead, totalBytesRead, totalBytesExpectedToRead in
    print("Bytes: \(bytesRead), Total Bytes: \(totalBytesRead), Total Bytes Expected: \(totalBytesExpectedToRead)")
}
```

This is not present anymore and I'm wondering how I can get the same functionality.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 15):

In Alamofire 4 the Progress APIs changed. All changes are explained in the [Alamofire 4.0 Migration Guide](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Alamofire%204.0%20Migration%20Guide.md).

To sum up the most important changes, that affect your use case:

```swift
// Alamofire 3
Alamofire.request(.GET, urlString, parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON)
.progress { bytesRead, totalBytesRead, totalBytesExpectedToRead in
    print("Bytes: \(bytesRead), Total Bytes: \(totalBytesRead), Total Bytes Expected: \(totalBytesExpectedToRead)")
}
```

can be achieved with

```swift
// Alamofire 4
Alamofire.request(urlString, method: .get, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
.downloadProgress { progress in
    print("Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
}
```

The returned `progress` object is of the [`Progress`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/progress) type of Apple's Foundation framework, so you can access the [`fractionCompleted`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/progress/1408579-fractioncompleted) property.

Detailed explanation of the changes can be found in the [Request Subclasses section](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Alamofire%204.0%20Migration%20Guide.md#request-subclasses) in the Alamofire 4.0 Migration guide.
The pull request [1455](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/pull/1455) in the Alamofire GitHub repo introduces the new Progress APIs and might be of help as well.

Answer (score 2):

**Alamofire 5, Swift 5**

```
AF.download(urlString)
        .downloadProgress { progress in
            print("Download Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
        }}
```