# Progress bar not changing asynchronously

Tags: swift, asynchronous, uisearchbar

I am trying to change the progress of a progress bar **asynchronously** with my Spotify request. How can I achieve this to make it work?

What I have so far:

```
searchClosure { result in
    switch result {
    case .success(let request):
        print("GOT")
        print("0.5")
        DispatchQueue.main.async { // No affect when I add this async
            self.userDelegate?.songProgress.setProgress(0.5, animated: true)
            print("loaded 0.5")
        }
        self.currentRequest = request
        self.getSongs(searchTerm: searchTerm)

    case .failure(_):
        self.getAccessToken()
        self.search(searchTermInput)
    }
}
```

In this closure, it prints `"loaded 0.5"` after all data is fetched and loaded into my table views, but I only want it to change as soon as my request was successful and got to that line in my code. However, `"0.5"` is printed as soon as my code gets to that point.

Why is this not working properly? You can also see I'm using the **main thread** for my `UI` as you are meant to.

**Alamofire** request (which goes to Spotify):

```
func searchClosure(completion: @escaping (RequestResult) -> ()) {
    Alamofire.request(searchTermURL, method: .get, headers: headers).responseJSON(completionHandler: { response in
        // Check if response is valid
        if let searchRequest = response.result.value as? JSONStandard {
            completion(.success(searchRequest))
        } else {
            completion(.failure(SpotifyError.failedToGetSearchResults))
        }
    })
}
```

Results are the same with or without an `asynchronous` dispatch.

This is also affecting another part of my code (more loading), so I hope the solution will work for both problems.

---

**If you have any questions, please ask**

Comment: Which library are you using for api call ?

Comment: @SagarChauhan **`Alamofire`**

Comment: Can you show the code of Alamofire request ?

Comment: Please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42727395/how-to-get-the-download-progress-in-bytes-using-alamofire-4

Comment: @SagarChauhan Oops, didn't realise I removed it :)

Comment: @SagarChauhan That question is not related - I am having problems with asynchronous tasks after the request loaded

Comment: BTW you shouldn't need to put `DispatchQueue.main.async { ... }` because Alamofire's progress and response closures are by default executed on the main thread.

Comment: @LinusGeffarth With or without, it still waits

Comment: When you submit a block of code to be dispatched asynchronously in the main thread, implies that the body that is currently in is executed in some _other_ thread. So, are you sure that your other tasks are not blocking? Also, where do you use `searchClosure` and what are the relevant methods for fetching the data and reloading the tableview?

Comment: @Alladinian Turns out I previously had the wrong closure in the lower part of my answer! Now that is fixed, the question about the thread. I *assume* my main thread is being blocked, but is there not a second thread I can put my UI on? (Or create more space on the main thread?)

Comment: @George_E_2 No. The idea is that every method affecting the UI _should_ be executed only in main thread, and every task that can be considered 'heavy' in a background one. A typical scenario is to perform your requests and data manipulation in a background queue and then wrap UI calls in a block to be submitted in the main queue. I hope that this makes sense...

Comment: @Alladinian That makes sense to me. When I did testing, it showed I was not using the background as shown here: **https://imgur.com/a/6rtSjsn**  How can I move my request to another thread?

Comment: Since you're using Alamofire, it already does this in your favor, so if I were you, I would carefully look at my own code by stepping in the debugger to get a better sense of the whole flow.

Comment: @Alladinian Where can I find your code...? Thanks

Comment: @Alladinian I downloaded your Alamofire project from GitHub, but unfortunately it was written in Swift 2.x. I did look through the code however, I didn't see how you have removed the requests from the main thread. Can you please explain how (maybe in an answer)?

Comment: Hi @George_E_2 and sorry for the confusion... Alamofire is _not_ mine (it's a project of Mattt Thompson - very smart guy who also did AFNetworking). What I really meant is "in your position... if I were you". Alamofire is not the problem, the requests are performed in the background, that's why you get your response in a closure...

Comment: I had similar issue with @escaping closure, is it called in searchClosure?

Comment: just to be sure, if you print self.userDelegate?.songProgress.progress just after setProgress(...
what you see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

main queue is single threaded thus if you are in the main thread and dispatched any other block of code using `DispatchQueue.main.async` it will not run until your current work finishs

I think you need to make sure that the call back of `searchClosure` is running from another thread than the main one and only enclose the stuff that use UI in Main thread

simple quick solution would be like

```
searchClosure { result in
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    switch result {
        case .success(let request):
            print("GOT")
            print("0.5")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.userDelegate?.songProgress.setProgress(0.5, animated: true)
                print("loaded 0.5")
            }
            self.currentRequest = request
            self.getSongs(searchTerm: searchTerm)

        case .failure(_):
            self.getAccessToken()
            self.search(searchTermInput)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Short, easy and simple clear answer. Description of why it doesn't work, and how to fix it. Thank you!